# Problema com posicionamento de include.php

Tags: html, css, posicionamento, include

Estou tendo um problema com o posicionamento do rodapé que fiz com `include.php`.

Criei um arquivo `include.php`, por enquanto a única coisa que tem nele é um `box` de onde será o rodapé, pois ainda estou testando.

Estou chamando ele no final de cada página, sempre antes do `body`.

```
<?php include "rodape.php"; ?>
```

O problema é que em apenas um das páginas ele está posicionado no final, nas outras ela aparece em locais diversos, no topo, mais a baixo um pouco, e em outras ele nem aparece.

Alguém saberia me dizer o que pode ser, se precisar de um trecho do código posso colocar aqui.

--> O html de uma das páginas que está dando o problema:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <Title>Portfolio - Julio Cesar </title>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900,300,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!--
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javaScript.js"></script>
    -->
</head>
<body>

    <div class="Conteiner"> <!--- INICIO CONTEINER-->   

    <header>    

        <div class="meu_logo">
            <a href="Index.php">Julio Cesar</a>
        </div>  

        <div id="caixatopo"></div>  


        <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="projetos.php">Projetos</a></li>
            <li><a href="Process.php">Processo</a></li>
            <li><a href="About.php">Sobre</a></li>
            <li><a href="Contact.php">Contato</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>   

        <div class="titulo_proclinica">
            <p>FATOR CLEAN <p>
        </div>


        <div class="categoria_fclean">
            <p>Web Design<p>
        </div>

        <div class="fator_imac1">
            <img src="imagens/fator_celan/fator imac1.png" />
        </div>  

        <div class="fator_imac2">
            <img src="imagens/fator_celan/fator imac2.png" />
        </div>  

        <div class="boxmarrom_1"></div>

        <div class="icones">
            <img src="imagens/fator_celan/icones.png" width="960px"  height:"auto"/>
        </div>

        <div class="fator_imac3">
            <img src="imagens/fator_celan/fator imac3.png" />
        </div>
    </div> <!--- FIM CONTEINER-->


    <?php include 'rodape.php'; ?>
</body>
```

O código do arquivo include:

```
<div class="box_rodape"></div>
```

O CSS do site está grande, não sei se poderia colocá-lo aqui.

--> CSS do rodapé, que é a div class `box_rodape`:

```
.box_rodape {
     background-color: rgb( 250, 31, 32 );
     left: 0;
     width: 960px;
     height: 300px;
     z-index:9999;   
}
```

Comment: Sim, acrescente o trecho de código para podermos ver como você está fazendo.

Comment: Parece ser um problema de posicionamento dos elementos presentes no rodapé e não um problema da inclusão do ficheiro nas diversas páginas. Ou seja, o CSS em algumas páginas não é compatível com o teu elemento em rodapé e o mesmo não fica visível na página apesar de estar presente no código fonte. Examinaste o código fonte da página após abrir a mesma no navegador?

Comment: Então @Zuul, dei uma olhada e não achei nada, da uma olhada no css do elemento do rodapé, é só um box vermelho por enquanto, além do mais, em uma das páginas, na index, ele está aparecendo normalmente.

Comment: @Juliocesar Compare a index com as outras páginas e veja se há diferenças no include.

Comment: @Juliocesar Podes indicar o que tem o ficheiro do rodapé? E se der para mostrar também o CSS.

Comment: @Zuul
O rodape.php é apenas isso:

<div class="box_rodape"></div>


E o css dessa div é isso:

.box_rodape {
     background-color: rgb( 250, 31, 32 );
     left: 0;
     width: 960px;
     height: 300px;
     position: absolute;
     z-index:9999;

}

Answer (score 1):

O CSS que você postou não diz se o box tem posição relativa ou absoluta ou qualquer outra.

`Z-index` só funciona se for declarada alguma position. E se ele for `position: absolute`  deve ser relativo ao pai dele que deve ter um `position: relative`.

Se o `body` for seu relativo você pode tentar 2 coisas:

1. Uma é dar um `height: 100%` no `body`
2. A outra, a mais recomendada, é você usar uma técnica chamada *Stick-Footer*. Jogue isso no Google que você vai aprender rapidinho.

Comment: Muito obrigado @dsantoro, vou dar uma olhada, valeu.